# Can biblatex produce a citation using a keyword from the bib file as reference?

Tags: biblatex

I'm using `biblatex` for my thesis, and I'd like to refer to my own publications differently than normal bibliographic references. An example might be to refer to them using the name of the conference they were published to. For example:

```
\begin{filecontents}{publications.bib}
  @inproceedings{Me2016,
     title = {Lorem Ipsum},
     author = {Me, John Et Al},
     keyword = {IJCAI~2016}
  }
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
  @inproceedings{Author97,
     title = {Sit Amet},
     author = {John Author}
  }
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{publications.bib}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib} % normal bibliography

\begin{document}

My work~\cite{Me2016} extends the work by \textcite{Other97}.

\end{document}
```

This example should print something like 
    My work [IJCAI 2016] extends the work by Author [1].

Note: I remember seeing a similar question years ago (and I though "ah! I'll use that in my thesis!"), so it's probably a duplicate, but I cannot find it now that it's needed).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds as if you are looking for the `shorthand` field:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{publications.bib}
  @inproceedings{Me2016,
     title = {Lorem Ipsum},
     author = {Me, John Et Al},
     keyword = {IJCAI~2016},
     shorthand = {IJCAI~2016}
  }
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{biblio.bib}
  @inproceedings{Other97,
     title = {Sit Amet},
     author = {John Author}
  }
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{publications.bib}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib} % normal bibliography

\begin{document}

My work~\cite{Me2016} extends the work by \textcite{Other97}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! How is it going to appear with `\printbibliography`?

Comment: @gigabytes The shorthand will also be used in the bibliography

Comment: Great! That’s exactly what I needed!